# Searching for Birth Records In Philadelphia, PA for births in 1914

Tags: birth-records, pennsylvania, 1910s

I would like to find the birth records for my father who was born in 1914 in Philadelphia, PA.   What would be the best way to proceed to find those records? My goal is to track down his father's immigration information and trace him back to Germany.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the helpful overview "[How to Find Pennsylvania Birth Records](https://familysearch.org/wiki/en/How_to_Find_Pennsylvania_Birth_Records)" (FamilySearch Wiki), especially [Births_After_1905](https://familysearch.org/wiki/en/How_to_Find_Pennsylvania_Birth_Records#Births_After_1905)

The wiki page does need to be updated: as of 2017, birth records are available from 1906 to 1911. And the PHMC (Pennsylvania Historical & Museum Commission) link to the [Birth Indices](http://www.phmc.pa.gov/Archives/Research-Online/Pages/Birth-Indices.aspx#.VuGIHTGYH5d) has changed several times since the records went online.

A number of resources have Pennsylvania birth records, but you will either need to wait 3 more years for 1914 records to be opened (due to the 105 year restriction) or be creative using birth record alternatives, such as those listed at [Substitute Records For United States Birth Information](https://familysearch.org/wiki/en/Substitute_Records_For_United_States_Birth_Information)

Several questions here at GFH.SE have covered creating timelines and collecting all U.S. records for immigrants, before trying to make the jump back to their country of origin.